# compiling xdebug on linux -> passing 32 bit option to ./configure

Tags: xdebug, configure

Greetings!

When trying to compile xdebug, is there a way to pass it a 32-bit option?

What I have right now is this:

./configure  --with-php-config=/opt/lampp/bin/php-config

... or is there a better way to obtain a 32-bit bin of xdebug?

Thaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old question, but had the same issue and I didn't want to install a 32 bit Linux distribution just for this.

This is what I did:

```
sudo aptitude install g++-multilib
CFLAGS=-m32 CPPFLAGS=-m32 CCASFLAGS=-m32 ./configure --with-php-config=/opt/lampp/bin/php-config
sudo cp modules/xdebug.so /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/
```

Source: http://montenasoft.com/en/blog/how-install-pecl-php-extension-64bit-linux-while-you-are-using-32bit-xampp

Answer (score 0):

... never mind. Installed Vector Linux Light on VirtualBox, installed xampp with dev package on that and compiled xdebug against that. Then transfered xdebug.so into the proper xampp install and it worked like a charm.